# asp.net application loads infinitely randomly

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, infinite-loop

I am having asp.net application which works well for 99% of time but approx once in a day it start infinite loading and **doesn't show any errors** like Timeout or redirect loop
and after if do recycle for this application in IIS then it starts working.

Few things are there which seams doubtful:

->There are 3 third party API integrations, which is called approx every 15-30 minutes using timer for each integration for importing data and those data are stored in database in background process(threads).

->Another is that in IIS setting is done for redirecting from domain.com to www.domain.com.

I am not having direct access to IIS,
but i was given detail that there are 500+ threads for this application's w3wp.exe and cpu is normal.

Can anyone give some suggestion or help?